# How to prove $-J_0(\pi \mu) = J_2(\pi \mu)$ where $\mu$ is a solution of $J_1(\pi x) = 0$?

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am doing phased array antenna research and am trying to understand a final step in the Taylor circular aperture distribution solution.  The solution Taylor presents has removable singularities at:

$$\frac{J_1(\pi x)}{1-(x/\mu)^2}$$

when $x=\mu$, where as stated in the questions $\mu$ is a solution of $J_1(\pi x) = 0$.
Applying L'Hôpital to this, I get:

$$\frac{2}{\pi \mu}(\lim_{x \to \mu} \frac{J_1(\pi x)}{1-(x/\mu)^2})=\frac{-J_0(\pi \mu)+J_2(\pi \mu)}{2}$$

but Taylor has:

$$\frac{2}{\pi \mu}(\lim_{x \to \mu} \frac{J_1(\pi x)}{1-(x/\mu)^2})=-J_0(\pi \mu)$$

implying that 
$J_2(\pi \mu) = -J_0(\pi \mu)$.

How can I prove that this is true?

I have checked and both these solutions are equal, and I have checked that $-J_0(\pi \mu) = J_2(\pi \mu)$ using C++ and it is indeed true for all $\mu$ which I have listed below:

$\mu$ = 1.2196699, 2.2331306, 3.2383154, 4.2410628, 5.2427643, 6.2439216, 7.2447598, 8.2453948, 9.2458927, 10.2462933;

For reference, here is a plot of the two functions which should be equal for all $\mu$:

[image: -J0 vs J2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the [recurrence relation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E1)

$$J_{\nu-1}(z)+J_{\nu+1}(z)=\frac{2\nu}{z}J_\nu(z)$$

Let $\nu=1$ and $z=\pi\mu$, and use the fact that $J_1(\pi\mu)=0$.

Comment: Congratulation to Squid for finding this!

Comment: J. M. Thank you so much!